# Comparing values within an object array for one specific field for Mergesort. Beginner question about using compareTo

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort, compareto

Pretty simply, we have to implement a sorting function of our own choice to sort through a database of customers. The customers are imported from an excel file and stored in an array. I have chosen Mergesort to make a different question involving big O notation a slam dunk.

Here's the import and the creation of the array

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("customers.csv")); Customer[] customers = new Customer[1000];`

The customer class looks like this
`
class Customer implements Comparable{

```
    private int cusNo;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    //The constructor
    public Customer(int cusNo, String dateOfBirth, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.cusNo = cusNo;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

The problem I have as described in the title comes with the comparison section within the merge method of the mergsort algo.

```
     Customer[] tempCus = new Customer[1000];
 int c = 0;
 while(i < mid && j < UpperB) {
     
     if(customers.getFirstName[i].compareTo.(customers.getFirstName[b])<=0) {
         tempCus[i] = Customer[i];
```

I honestly have no idea how to use the compareTo method in this situation given the construction of the class and would really appreciate a solution/ a context specific explanation or if I've gone down a bad path a bit of redirection. I have gone with what I've gone with as a bit of a shot in the dark and after multiple different attempts to get the syntax for compareTo correct. Quite confident compareTo is the correct choice, but the implementation is beyond me. Am generally unsure of how to call back a specific value in an array without the extra difficulty of the method and the bracket forrest that comes with it.

Using the in built sort() method is not an option given the task

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that but either have `Customer` implement `Comparable<Customer>` and implement the method `compareTo(Customer other)` or use a `Comparator<Customer>` and implement the method `compare(Customer left, Customer right)`. The implementation would be basically the same with the objects being `this` and `other` or `left` and `right`. Then compare the relevant elements one after another until you've compared all or the result is != 0.

A simple way to get a comparator would be something like this:

```
Comparator<Customer> comparator = Comparator.comparing( Customer:: getFirstName).thenComparing( Customer::getLastName );
```

Then use it like this (reusing your code so I didn't check that for correctness):

```
//assuming i and b are correct indices
if(comparator.compare(tempCus[i], tempCus[b])<=0) {
  ...
```

Since you want to use `Comparable` here's an *example* (think about it and expand as needed):

```
class Customer implements Comparable<Customer> {
   public int compareTo(Customer other) { 
      //or: int result = this.firstName.compareTo(other.getFirstName());
      int result = String.compare(this.firstName, other.getFirstName());

      //0 means the strings are equal, otherwise we're done
      if( result != 0 ) {
        return result;
      }
      
      result = String.compare(this.lastName, other.getLastName());
      
      //if needed add more comparisons here
   
      return result;
   }
}
```

Then just use it like `if(tempCus[i].compareTo(tempCus[b]) <= 0)`

Comment: thanks for the answer Thomas. I don't think i can use a Comparator, it's not in the purview of the course and I haven't seen one before so that would probably cause it's own issues. Any chance you could give an example of implementing the compareTo(Customer other) solution that you mentioned?

Comment: @LosBluefist added it :)

Comment: Thank you very much man. Will get to figuring it out